# React component re-rendering many times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

i have  a react component thats keep re-rendering idk why but i think the reason is the data fetching

data code :

```
export function KPI_Stock_Utilisation() {
  const [kpi_stock_utilisation, setKpi_stock_utilisation] = useState([{}]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5137/KPI_Stock_Utilisation").then((response) => {
        setKpi_stock_utilisation((existingData) => {
        return response.data;
      });
    });
  }, []);
  console.log('data get')

  return kpi_stock_utilisation;
}
```

this log displayed many times , and the log in the component too

component code :

```
import React from "react";
import { KPI_Stock_Utilisation } from "../../Data/data";
import { useEffect } from "react";

export default function WarehouseUtilisChart(props) {

  let kpi_stock_utilisations =KPI_Stock_Utilisation();
  let Stock_utilisation = (kpi_stock_utilisations.length / 402) * 100;
    console.log('component render')

return (
    <div>
            <p>{kpi_stock_utilisations}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

im new with react i tried useEffect inside the componenets but its not working

Comment: You are using useState and useEffect in a function that is not a component. It might be better to wrap it in a custom hook.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the react custom hook **KPI_Stock_Utilisation** several times will for sure render more than once.
in your case I suggest you use useEffect in the same component as I will show you.

```
import React,{useEffect,useRef} from "react";
import { KPI_Stock_Utilisation } from "../../Data/data";
import axios from 'axios';

export default function WarehouseUtilisChart(props) {

 const [kpi_stock_utilisation, setKpi_stock_utilisation] = useState([{}]);
 const stock_utilisation= useRef(0);

useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5137/KPI_Stock_Utilisation").then((response) => {
      stock_utilisation.current = (response.data.length / 402) * 100;
        setKpi_stock_utilisation(response.data);
    });


//this will guarantee that the api will be called only once
  }, []);

 //you should see this twice, one with the value 0, and another one, the calculated data
    console.log('component render',stock_utilisation.current)

return (
    <div>
            <p>{kpi_stock_utilisations}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To note, if you call this component from more than one location, for sure it will render several times - keep that in mind.

On the other hand, all your variables should **always** start with a lower case and try to name your variables like this: instead of **kpi_stock_utilisation** change it to **kpiStockUtilisation** for a better coding practice

Answer (score 0):

You got into infinite loop.

Its hard to explain why it doesn't work as expected, but I can try.

First of all, useEffect with empty array of dependencies works like componentDidMount and fires only after (!) first render.

So you have some value returned from your `let kpi_stock_utilisations =KPI_Stock_Utilisation();` then it rendered, after this your useEffect fires a request and set state, setting of state trigger re-render and new value to return, this new value trigger your parent component to return `let kpi_stock_utilisations =KPI_Stock_Utilisation();` might run again.

If you are trying to create a custom hook for fetching some info, follow [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

I hope it helped you